# How to use React-Router with a model

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As you can see from the [React todomvc](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/react/js)[1](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/react/js), one way to make sure that the ui stays up to date with the model is to have the model subscribe to the render function (as shown below) so that the UI renders on every change.

```
function render() {
    React.render(
        <TodoApp model={model}/>,
        document.getElementById('todoapp')
    );
}

model.subscribe(render);
render();
```

If using the React router in an app, you have to wrap the React.render call in the router, as show[as shown by this demo](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/animations/app.js)

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('example'));
});
```

So, how would you use the Router if you also needed to update the model? i.e. how to wrap `React.render` in both the router and the `function render`? This creates problems with scope

```
 function render() {
        Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {
        React.render(
            <TodoApp model={model}/>,
            document.getElementById('todoapp')
        );
        });
    }

    model.subscribe(render);
    render();
```

Comment: Could you provide more context on where your `model` instance comes from? Part of a solution would be to decide where the model state should be instantiated from and where it should live, so re-rendering can be triggered from within the component itself.

Comment: @insin sorry about that, think of it exactly as in the TodoMVC demo, that's where I saw the wrapper around the model to update the UI https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/react/js

Comment: You forgot to add the links, the [1] and [2] part.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 sorry, added the links now

Comment: @TomokoYamaguchi little late, but see solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you are going to be creating a fully react app and using react router, then I personally think using this model is not really the best way of going about it. Ultimately I think a better solution to all of this would be not using this model at all and just using react to handle all the changes. However, if you were to try do this with the existing model and react-router I would make a reference to the model in state at the root of your app then pass a setState to the models subscribe method.
http://jsfiddle.net/xw8uc0nf/3/

```
var model = TodoModel

var App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function(){
    return({localModel: model});
},
componentDidMount: function(){
    model.subscribe(this.updateModel.bind(this))
},

updateModel: function(){
    this.setState({localModel: model});
},
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>Super TODO app</header>
        <TodoApp model={@state.localModel} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Comment: +1 for not using models at all. Although this solution works, it's also a little weird, as the author points out. Understanding Flux, and the unidirectional flow of data, makes using React a lot simpler and more powerful. Try getting rid of the model, moving your API calls into your actions, using a dispatcher, and making your stores skinnier: https://cask.scotch.io/2014/10/V70cSEC.png